# Fourier coefficients of a trigonometric series : identical to trigonometric coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

In this thread :

[Is $H(\theta) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \cos (2\pi n_k \theta)$ for a given sequence $n_k$ equal a.e. to a continuous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237368/is-h-theta-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k-cos-2-pi-n-k-theta?rq=1)

Brad Rodgers answers the question, but I don't understand why the Fourier coefficients of the function $\sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{1}{|k|}e^{2i\pi n_k}$, are the $\frac{1}{|k|}$ !

Of course it seems obvious but it is not easy to prove I think. There is trigometric series with Fourier coefficients that are not their trigonometric coefficients.

How can we prove this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series that defines $H$ converges in $L^2[0,1],$ hence in $L^1[0,1].$ Therefore

$$\hat H (n) = \int_0^1 (\sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{1}{|k|}e^{2i\pi n_kt})e^{-i2\pi nt}\, dt = \sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{1}{|k|}(\int_0^1 e^{2i\pi n_kt}e^{-i2\pi nt}\, dt)$$

for all $n.$ Hence $\hat H (n_k) = 1/|k|, k \ne 0,$ and $\hat H (n) = 0$ for all other $n.$

Comment: How can I have missed that ! Simple and fast, thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Just one question ! Why is there convergence in $L^2$ (or $L^1$) ? The norm of $t \mapsto e^{2i \pi n_k t}/k$ is $1/|k|$ both $L_1$ or $L^2$ thus not summable !

Comment: No, $\int_0^1 |\sum a_n e^{2\pi i n t}|^2\, dt = \sum |a_n|^2.$

Comment: Ok fine ! And what about the L^1 convergence ?

Comment: L^2 convergence implies L^1 convergence in any finite measure space.

Comment: Ok ! I will take a look at all those things. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48495/discussion-between-j-mayol-and-zhw).

Comment: No, I don't do chat, sorry.

Comment: Ok no problem. So I just need a precision : how do you intervert the sum and the integral in your answer ? Lebesgue theorem does not work here.

Comment: It's just L^1 convergence. If $f_n \to f$ in $L^1,$ then $\int f_n \to \int f.$ Apply this to the partial sums.

Comment: OK thanks ! I just didn't see it.